# Swift: Cant append Items to Array with two values

Tags: arrays, object, swift

So my code is like this (Playground)

```
import Foundation

public class Node {}

var test: Node = Node()
var arrayTest = [Int, Node]()

arrayTest.append(2, test)

Error xCode shows @ append Line: Accessing members of protocol type value 'Int' is unimplemented
```

But if I change the second array value from "Node" to "String" everything works fine.
If I delete "Int, " so that its only a Node Array it works too.
What am I missing? Why doesn't it work like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to store `(Int, Node)` tuples in the array, then you should enclose the tuple in parenthesis, either when specifying the array type and when using `append`:

```
var test: Node = Node()
var arrayTest = [(Int, Node)]()
//               ^         ^

arrayTest.append((2, test))
//               ^       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Appending a tuple to an array worked as expected when my tuple had 2 elements. When I jumped to a tuple with 4 elements, then I got the "Accessing members..." message.

The straightforward approach didn't work.

```
myArray.append(tupleItem1, tupleItem2, tupleItem3, tupleItem4) // ! Accessing members of protocol type value ...
```

The suggested workaround didn't work.

```
myArray.append((tupleItem1, tupleItem2, tupleItem3, tupleItem4)) // ! Missing argument for parameter #2 in call
```

What did work was a two-step append.

```
let myElement = (tupleItem1, tupleItem2, tupleItem3, tupleItem4)
myArray.append(myElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

And if otherwise you're building a dictionary, then it will look something like this:

```
var arrayTest = Dictionary<Int, Node>()
arrayTest[2] = test
```